# Screen capture error - what does it mean?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I'm using this call:

```
driver.save_screenshot('/tmp/screen1.png')
```

Which results in this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Could not convert screen
shot to base64 - Error: Unable to load canvas into base64 string
```

I can't find any information on this error.

Comment: Have you tried `driver.get_screenshot_as_file(‘/Screenshots/foo.png’)`? doc [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=screenshot#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.save_screenshot)

Comment: Yes, driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/tmp/screen1.png') results in the same error.

Comment: It is a well known issue when the screenshot is too big, like 5000px X 5000px and bigger. As I know it is not the issue for Chrome Driver.

Comment: OK, I can get it to work sometimes, how can I trap for the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Selenium [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8200) has the exact error message you are reporting and was marked as a duplicate of [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2219).

In both bug reports, the cause of the failure to take a screenshot is the size of the web page, which is apparently too large for the browser to handle. People commenting on the reports have reported that Chrome seems to work in cases where Firefox will fail.